# Is it true that if you could see and track every atom there is, you could see the entire history of the universe?

Tags: universe, determinism

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWO-cvGETRQ

Is it true that if you could see and track every atom there is, you could see the entire history of the universe?

I thought that when matter is changed through chemical or physical phenomena, some information would be permanently lost at a certain point, but the video seems to suggest otherwise. How true is that?

Comment: This seems to be asking whether or not the universe, at the smallest levels, is predictable and deterministic.

Comment: Every "atom there is" did not exist for the entire history of the universe.

Comment: In physics, we test the truth of hypotheses with experiments. What experiment do you propose?